# How can I send localstorage data from JavaScript ajax call and print return data from views in Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

I have stored some data on localStorage( Itemnames and ItemIds), now I want to send itemid's to django views from ajax. I have basics knowledge of django and learning Javascript. I tried to figureit out by myself but its been more than 4 days I could not succeed, any help will be highly appreciated.

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var compare = localStorage.getItem("comparisionItems");
    var compareObj = JSON.parse(compare);
    
    var data_url = window.location.href;
    console.log(compare)
    console.log(compareObj)
    
   
      
      $.ajax({
        url: './compare',
        type: "POST",
        data: {'compare_id': compareObj },
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Some problem on passing data");
        }
        
    });
});
```

[image: After getting the localstorageitmes, the console return looks like this:]

My views:

```
def compare(request):
is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
    compare_id= request.POST.getlist('compare_id[itemIds]')
    """compare_id=request.POST.getlist('itemIds[]')  """
   
    """compare_id = request.POST.get('compare_id')"""
    product = get_object_or_404(Products, id=compare_id)
    context={ 'product':product}
   
    """ return render (request, './ecommerce/compare.html', context)"""
    return render (request, './compare.html', context)
else:
    context = None
    return render(request,'./compare.html', context)
```

How can I get the products which have id's pass by ajax? And is there any different ways to pass those products to the template or I can do it just like the regular Django context process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass json string from your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: './compare',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({'compare_id': compare }),
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            if (key == "products") {
                for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
                     var wishlistUrl = "{% url 'ecommerce:add_to_wishlist' %}";
                      var div = '<div class="compare-col compare-product">';
                      div += '<a href="#" class="btn remove-product"><i class="w-icon-times-solid"></i></a>';
                      div += '<div class="product text-center"><figure class="product-media">';
                      div += '<a href="product.html"><img src="' + data[key][i].product_feature_image.image.url + '" alt="Product" width="228" height="257" />';
                      div += '</a><div class="product-action-vertical"><a href="#" class="btn-product-icon btn-cart w-icon-cart"></a>';
                      div += '<a href="#" class="btn-product-icon btn-wishlist w-icon-heart" title="Wishlist" attr_id="' + data[key][i].id + '" ';
                      div += ' action_url="' + wishlistUrl + '">';
                      div += '</a></div></figure><div class="product-details"><h3 class="product-name"><a href="product.html">' + data[key][i].name + '</a></h3>';
                      div += '</div></div></div>';
                      $('#parentDivElementId').append(div); #--- your parent div element id
                   }
               }
          })
     },
     error: function () {
          alert("Some problem on passing data");
     }
  });
```

And in your `views.py`

Get POST data first

```
 import json
 from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, render 

 def compare(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        compare_ids = data['compare_id']["itemIds"] if 'itemIds' in data['compare_id'] else []

        # since here multiple ids may come you need to use `filter` instead you will get 
        get() returned more than one Products -- it returned 2!

        products = Products.objects.filter(id__in=compare_ids).values()
        return JsonResponse({'products ': list(products) }, safe=False) #---- since Queryset is not JSON serializable

    else:
        context = None
        return render(request,'./compare.html', context)
```

In your console you can see your `products` data.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241252/discussion-on-answer-by-user8193706-how-can-i-send-localstorage-data-from-javasc).

Comment: its not showing. I am trying new approach for this. I have another issue, can you help me on that?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807221/how-to-save-billing-and-shipping-address-in-django-form

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax you should stringify the data part like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    // rest of the code
    data: JSON.stringify({'compare_id': compareObj}),
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // access your response as data.product
    },
    // rest of the code
});
```

And then in you view:

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def compare(request):
   is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
   if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
      compare_id = json.loads(request.POST.get('compare_id'))
      ids = compare_id.get('compare_id')
      # ids will be list of ids and you can get first id with index
      product = get_object_or_404(Products, id=ids[0])
      # rest of code
      return JsonResponse({'product': product})
```

Comment: Needs appropriate content type when sending json. The default is form encoded

Comment: @charlietfl you mean from ajax ?

Comment: Yes, exactly....

Comment: @chartlietfl done sir! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have one confusion here, from my localStorage I need to take ids list from itemIds as shown in the image attached above, can I achieve it from your way?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what the answer is doing i guess.

Comment: Still there is problem, https://imgur.com/u5mMUg1

Comment: Someone godman gave my question negative number but they not know the struggle we are doing to learn and taking help from community. I thought it would not pass id itself direct that's why I asked question, and infact I got error when I tested but I got negative marks to my question. I will be thankful @Ahtisham if you can help me how I can take values from itemIds as there are two objects images and itemIds

Comment: @BishalKhanal It was not me.

Comment: What issue are you having with my solution ? The image you posted in comment only shows Internal Server Error which gives no information regarding error please show what error you get in the terminal.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is get the id of item from local storage, pass that id via ajax to views and show that product details on template. 

https://imgur.com/Ti2JH8X

Comment: @BishalKhanal I have updated the answer check.

Comment: Its throwing error only 
The view ecommerce.views.compare didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: I tried @user8193706 way also but no luck yet